# Integral Ito (stohastic integral) of Poisson process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, poisson-process

I need to find $D\int_{0}^{t} N_{s}dW_{s}$, where $N_{s}$ is Poisson process and $N_{s}$ and $W_{s}$ are independent. How can i do it?

Comment: What does $D$ stand for ?